# RadGrid - get textbox in edit mode

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have an issue working with the telerik radgrid control. I am trying to use javascript to access a textbox when the grid is in edit mode.

My code looks like the following:

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" GridLines="None" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True"
        AllowSorting="False" AllowAutomaticInserts="True" PageSize="10" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True"
        OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound" AllowMultiRowEdit="False" AllowPaging="False"
        DataSourceID="DataSource1" OnItemUpdated="RadGrid1_ItemUpdated" AllowFilteringByColumn="False"
        OnItemDeleted="RadGrid1_ItemDeleted" OnItemInserted="RadGrid1_ItemInserted" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        OnDataBound="RadGrid1_DataBound">
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
        <MasterTableView Width="100%" CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom" DataKeyNames="Id"
            DataSourceID="DataSource1" HorizontalAlign="NotSet" EditMode="EditForms">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn">
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="MyImageButton" />
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete this product?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                    ConfirmTitle="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                    UniqueName="DeleteColumn">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="MyImageButton" />
                </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" Display="false" ReadOnly="true" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Manufacturer" HeaderText="Manufacturer" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Configuration" HeaderText="Configuration" />
                <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataField="TypeId" HeaderText="Type" UniqueName="PartsType"
                    DataSourceID="PartsTypeDataSource" ListTextField="Name" ListValueField="Id" />
```

What I am after is that, during edit mode, when the user selects a certain value from the dropdown list **'PartsType'**, one of the other fields - eg **'Manufacturer'** will be shown/hide.

I could get the dropdown value (in javascript) by attaching a javascript function to the dropdownlist:

```
function PartsTypeIndexChanged(sender, args) {
    var selectedValue = args.get_item()._text;

}
```

I just dont know which method to use to get the **'Manufacturer'** field, so I can show/hide it.

Could anyone please help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach could be to use RadControls client-side static API

```
$telerik.findElement(gridDOMElement, "Manufacturer");
```

This will help you access the column editor - I suppose it is ASP.NET TextBox rendered as input. For numeric or date columns the editor will probably be Telerik client component so you have to use findControl instead of findElement.

More info here:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/telerik-static-client-library.html

Good luck

Comment: could you please tell me what the gridDOMElement is supposed to be?

Comment: gridDOMElement is the DOM element of the RadGrid control. You can get it in different ways. The easiest (but not the fastest) would be to use the same method 
$telerik.findElement(document, "RadGrid1");

On the other hand, if you already have the client component object (not the DOM element) you can do something like this: 
radGrid.get_element();

Comment: Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/set-controls-attribute-like-enable-disable-on-insert-edit-mode-using-jquery.aspx